# On Multiple JVM, Java's UUID.randomUUID, what is probability for collision?

Tags: java, uuid

I am building microservice based architecture where multiple microservices are running in parallel for horizontal scalability.
All services are using same algorithm to generate UUID (UUID.randomUUID), once UUID is generated it is saved in database and returned to calling service. After few seconds caller sends request to verify status of txn with UUID.

In relational DB UUID is primary key, We have seen collision of UUID generated by different services. Questions

1. what is possibility of duplicate UUID across JVMs?
2. Should we add some logic in code to verify collision before saving it to DB?

Comment: Most real services currently in place actually just pretend that collisions are not a thing - as the probability is so low. Same for collisions with hashes, like SHA or MD5. Obviously it depends on the amount you are planning to handle but typically this fact is indeed ignored for most cases.

Comment: We are testing 1M transaction with 4 micro services and we can few hundred failures each time due to UUID collision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What is possibility of duplicate UUID across JVMs.

It is possible, but the probability is vanishingly small.  The Wikipedia page on the Birthday Problem has a [probability table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table) that can be used to estimate the likelihood of a collision.

For example, with 128 bit random UUIDs (and a high quality random number generator) the table says that you would need to generate 2.6 x 10<sup>10</sup> UUIDs for the probability of a collision to reach 1 in 10<sup>18</sup>.

Earlier in the article you will find the mathematics on calculating ... and estimating ... the probabilities.

> 2. Should we add some logic in code to verify collision before saving it to DB?

It really depends on the number of UUIDs you are likely to generate and store, and on the probability of collision that you are willing to accept.

However, if you are concerned by the possibility of a collision, you could just make the UUID columns a unique keys in the relevant database tables.  It is more likely that a transaction will fail due to a hardware error than you will get a collision leading to a uniqueness constraint failure!

---

Followup questions:

> I am not sure if this probability is for one generator or multiple?

The number of generators is not relevant, provided that they are >independent< random number generators.

> As we have seen collision few hundred times with 1 million txns.

The mathematics don't lie.  If you have seen a collision a few hundred times with 1 million transactions then *something else* is wrong.  The assumptions are incorrect.

For example:

- Maybe you are using a weak PRNG.
- Maybe you are using a fixed seed or using a poor source of entropy when seeding the PRNGs.
- Maybe you are modifying (e.g. shortening) the UUIDs in a way that drastically reduces their effective bit count.
- Maybe something in your UUID generation methodology is causing UUIDs to be issued twice in a row ... sometimes.
- Maybe objects are being duplicated when they shouldn't be ... and you end up with two copies of an object with the same UUID.
- Maybe someone / something is faking UUIDs.

There are a lot of things that you need to check before you start doubting the mathematics.

> My doubt is all 4 services are using same algorithm the probability will increase.

As I said, the number of generators does not alter the mathematics.

Comment: Thanks for links, but I am not sure if this probability is for one generator or multiple? As We have seen collision few hundred times with 1 million txns. My doubt is all 4 services are using same algorithm the probability will increase.

Comment: Thanks @stephen, I found the rootcause now. As you mentioned, I did bit more digging into logs at DB side and found there was some script running which was creating this confusion. Appreciate your help.